# How to sort a CSS stylesheet by combined selector and value

Tags: css, sorting, stylesheet

How do I sort or output a CSS stylesheet to only combine one property and value at a time?

Output could look like this:

```
    .class1,
    .class2,
    ...
    {color: lightgrey;)

    .class1,
    .class2,
    ...
    {background-color:blue;}

And so on...
```

Is this possible? I have looked at csscomb and neatcss but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: _Why_ do you need to do this? If you want to change a value only in one place, use Sass or Less.

Comment: Lol why you need to do this? The only reason is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYM-RJwSGQ8

Comment: The reason is that I am making a color options panel for a Wordpress theme where you can change different colors using a colorpicker. The options system needs to target all selectors with a specific value. I actually just found the solution, I will post it below :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in [http://www.codebeautifier.com/](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tw0dquy3mxnutmh/code_beautifier.jpg?dl=0) which has the options to merge selectors with the same properties. Very efficient, has just saved me a few hours of manual work. See the specific combination of options in this [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tw0dquy3mxnutmh/code_beautifier.jpg?dl=0).